# Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Tags: api, swiftui

I am trying to decode this api [TFL API](https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Line/Search/northern?serviceTypes=Regular)

But i keep getitng this error `typeMismatch(Swift.Array<Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))`

Here is my structs that i try to decode the json into

`

```
struct Route:Codable, Hashable {
    let type, input: String
    let searchMatches: [SearchMatch]
}

struct SearchMatch:Codable, Hashable{
    let type, lineID, mode, lineName: String
    let lineRouteSection: [LineRouteSection]
    let matchedRouteSections, matchedStops: [String]
}

struct LineRouteSection:Codable, Hashable{
    let type: String
    let routeID: Int
    let direction, destination, fromStation, toStation: String
    let serviceType, vehicleDestinationText: String
}
```

`

and here is where i try to decode the json
`

```
    func LoadRoutes(route:String, completion:@escaping ([Route]) -> ()) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Line/Search/"+route+"?serviceTypes=Regular") else {
            print("Invalid url...")
            return
        }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, _) in
            do {
                let routes = try JSONDecoder().decode([Route].self, from: data!)
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(routes)
                }
                
            } catch {
                print("ERROR")
                print(error)
                print("ERROR END")
            }
        }.resume()
        
    }
```

Is it a simple fix and if so how do i?

Comment: Can you add the json you are trying to decode?

Comment: API is in question but heres a link : https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Line/Search/northern?serviceTypes=Regular

Comment: `try JSONDecoder().decode(Route.self, from: data!)` - there is just one `Route` object in the json

Comment: but i get this error ```Cannot convert value of type 'Route' to expected argument type '[Route]'``` on line ``` DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(routes)
                } ```

Comment: well the completion has to take a single `Route` as well not  n array

Comment: Note, in addition to everything else, your struct model `LineRouteSection`, should match the json data.
 You should have:
 
 `enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
     case type = "$type"
     case routeID = "routeId"
     case direction, destination, fromStation, toStation, serviceType, vehicleDestinationText
 }`